# How to install google play services in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, drive

I am using Eclipse Mars to develop Android applications. I want to use the API for access to Google Drive files. I have found that I must use Google Play Services

In theory, I have installed Google Play Services, according to what Android SDK Manager is telling in its console (revision 42 is the number that appears in the Android SDK Manager console)

I have assumed that this means that I should have a google-play-services.jar in the directory where Google Play Services is installed and this jar should be added to my Android project. But there is no such jar, but instead, some documents and sample source

Any idea on what I should do?

Comment: *I am using Eclipse Mars to develop Android applications* better stop that and use android studio like the rest of the world

Comment: "I have assumed that this means that I should have a google-play-services.jar in the directory where Google Play Services is installed" -- AFAIK, their libraries are only available as Maven-style artifacts.

Comment: you are going to face more and more problems using Eclipse, since you are almost only one who still does (a dinosaur), and ther is just nobody else to help you. Soon you migrate to Android studio - less problems you will have.